# Regex for only numbers and/or letters and/or hyphens and/or spaces, in any combination or location

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a textbox to insure it contains only numbers and/or letters and/or hyphens and/or spaces, in any combination or location.

Assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The regex for

> *"only numbers and/or letters and/or hyphens and/or spaces, in any combination or location"*

is:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z -]*
```

Substitute the `*` for a `+` if you don't want to allow empty strings.

Check a [**demo** of how it works here](http://regex101.com/r/zN6tR1).

Comment: Thanks. I almost had it, but wasn't sure about the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a character class with all that you need + anchors for start and end of the string (to avoid partial matches)

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z -]+$
```