# PHP regex for letters numbers and hyphens

Tags: php, regex

How do you write the regex to check if a string contains only letters, numbers or hyphens? (-)

Comment: By Googling for literally any regex intro tutorial, ever.

Comment: This is one of the most basic regular expressions you could encounter.  Try looking at some documentation; [RexEgg](http://rexegg.com) is a great place to start.

Comment: I though it would be impossible to get it wrong. @MarkBaker just proved me incorrect.

Comment: Hence my point in posting this question. If someone just got it wrong, then it must not be so easy for some.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Does password must contain at least one of letters, numbers or hyphens OR can contain characters only from these groups, but for example be only letters like `"foobar"` (no digit or hyphen here)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for only numbers and/or letters and/or hyphens and/or spaces, in any combination or location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077532/regex-for-only-numbers-and-or-letters-and-or-hyphens-and-or-spaces-in-any-combi)

Comment: That's just a regex question, John's specifically marked this question with the PHP tag.

Comment: It's a duplicate, but not one that adds any value to the site, so it should be closed for a different reason in order to put it on the path to deletion.

Comment: John, I think it would be a mistake to take @Niet's comment as encouragement for this sort of question. I've downvoted, as I suspect have others, because no effort appears to have been expended or demonstrated. We see a lot of 1-rep users doing this, and we tend to ask them: what have you tried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below is the code that will do the trick.

```
$str = 'foo-bar!';
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/", $str)) {
    // contains only letters, numbers and hyphens
    echo 'only numbers letters and hyphens';
} else {
    // does not contain only letters, numbers, and hyphens
    echo 'fail';
}
```